# OutOfMemoryError. happen on phone when using images(not big images and i use largeheap)

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory, android-image

i have asked a lot question here about my application.
i have application on google play (js - design fashion & pattern maker).
i run the application on a lot devices and none of them do error.
but i have some phone that does error,
the phone are run android 7.1 and they galaxy s7(not just galaxy phones).

my app use a lot of images (almost 900), and i test it a lot, what can cause the OutOfMemoryRrror, it is not big image(on some phone it is work, and even on a same phone, it can work on one, but do the error on the other.).
i use in manifest this 2:

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"

but still it don't work.
the problem happen when the user add images to the main layout.

in the play console i see this:
[image]

so if i understand, after users install the app it take another 50MB in runtime, so i think, if the user don't have another 50MB, the app crash!

the error from the play console:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream (BitmapFactory.java:620)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream (BitmapFactory.java:455)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream (Drawable.java:1152)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie (ResourcesImpl.java:857)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable (ResourcesImpl.java:708)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:863)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:928)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:157)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:145)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:71)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:67)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:769)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:377)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
  at com.royijournogmail.designjs.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:859)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6757)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2704)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2812)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1528)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6311)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

i am very sure it is not happen because big images, i think it just because the run time usage,after the installation.

some can help what can i do? if i will use library that handle the imageviews, it will help? or can i put in google play that you need 100MB free to download the app? i dont want that for some user the app will crash!.

thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no way for us to point to a problem unless we see your code. Does it seem that you are not properly recycling images, probably not using recycler view? Using wrong contexts to load images? Obviously, you are not caching images properly. I would advise you to use `Glide`.

Comment: yes, i am not using any recycle view... try to use glide now..

Comment: Implement a recycler view, use Glide and choose appropriate disk caching strategy. Also, take care of the context you use to load images.